# Swift 3 : Can not convert value of type 'CircleMenu' to expected argument type 'CircleMenu'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates

I have a custom button subclass of UIButton

```
/// A Button object with pop ups buttons
open class CircleMenu: UIButton {
  /// The object that acts as the delegate of the circle menu.
  @IBOutlet weak open var delegate: /*AnyObject?*/ CircleMenuDelegate?

......................
```

further down in that same class there is a function that detects when a button will be selected.

```
func buttonHandler(_ sender: CircleMenuButton) {
    guard let platform = self.platform else { return }
    self.delegate?.circleMenu?(self, buttonWillSelected: sender, atIndex: sender.tag)
    let circle = CircleMenuLoader(radius: CGFloat(distance),
                                  strokeWidth: bounds.size.height,
                                  platform: platform,
                                  color: sender.backgroundColor)

    if let container = sender.container { // rotation animation
      sender.rotationAnimation(container.angleZ + 360, duration: duration)
      container.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: container)
    }

    if let buttons = buttons {
      circle.fillAnimation(duration, startAngle: -90 + Float(360 / buttons.count) * Float(sender.tag)) { [weak self] _ in
        self?.buttons?.forEach { $0.alpha = 0 }
      }
      circle.hideAnimation(0.5, delay: duration) { [weak self] _ in
        if self?.platform?.superview != nil { self?.platform?.removeFromSuperview() }
      }

      hideCenterButton(duration: 0.3)
      showCenterButton(duration: 0.525, delay: duration)

      if customNormalIconView != nil && customSelectedIconView != nil {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + duration, execute: {
          self.delegate?.circleMenu?(self, buttonDidSelected: sender, atIndex: sender.tag)

        })
      }
    }
  }
```

to go with the delegate variable above, I've got another class to manage the delegate.

```
@objc public protocol CircleMenuDelegate {
    @objc optional func circleMenu(_ circleMenu: CircleMenu, buttonWillSelected sender: UIButton, atIndex: Int)
}
```

I am trying to access the data, specifically the index of the button that is being pressed in another class, and just while I'm playing around if set it up within a button

```
class AppMainViewController: UIViewController, CircleMenuDelegate  {

    @IBAction func getValue(_ sender: Any) {
        CircleMenuDelegate.circleMenu(CircleMenu, buttonWillSelected: UIButton, atIndex: Int)
    }
}
```

This is throwing me an error "Can not convert value of type 'CircleMenu' to expected argument type 'CircleMenu'"

------EDIT------

just adding the circleMenu call in a function within the AppMainViewController class stops the type error above but then i don't know how to get the values of buttonWillSelected and atIndex out.

```
func circleMenu(_ cm: CircleMenu, buttonWillSelected sender: UIButton, atIndex: Int) {
    print(sender.tag)
}
```

Also some of the textbooks, online searches show something similar to:

```
CircleMenu().delegate = self
```

however there is no option to select delegate after CircleMenu().[dropdown options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvTVk.png)

Comment: What is `CircleMenu` in `....ircleMenu(CircleMenu, buttonWillSel....`.??

Comment: CircleMenu is the class name..... "open class CircleMenu: UIButton {"

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect that you are passing Class name `CircleMenu` inside the delegate method call instead of object of `CircleMenu` Class.

```
CircleMenuDelegate.circleMenu(**Circle Menu Object Here**, buttonWillSelected: UIButton, atIndex: Int)
```

Comment: ok so how does this work? because in "fun buttonHandler" I'm using "self.delegate?.circleMenu?(self, " which like you said is the Class name.  This is also the case in the CircleMenuDefegate "circleMenu(_ circleMenu: CircleMenu" it just throws an error in the IBAction "    @IBAction func getValue(_ sender: Any) {
        CircleMenuDelegate.circleMenu(CircleMenu, buttonWillSelected: UIButton, atIndex: Int)
    }"

Comment: Have you somewhere assigned `button.delegate = self`? `delegate` from this line of code `@IBOutlet weak open var delegate:`.

Comment: And have you implemented `func circleMenu(_ circleMenu:` method inside `AppMainViewController`?

Comment: there is no button object within the buttonHandler(...  function or even the CircleMenu class.  The button handler is just getting some data from another class and passing to CircleMenu class.   Im missing something, think i need to stop looking at it for a while.  thanks for the help bru

Comment: yeah the error is coming from function circleMenu(  inside AppMainViewController

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding of delegate concept implementation in your code.

Comment: yes there is a problem.. i can not set CircleMenu.delegate = self.. very few options of whats available after the dot.